# Push property of undefined

Tags: javascript

Could someone shine a ray of light into why one is getting "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined " my js skill is limited.

```
 function Position(position) {
      if (!position) {
        throw new Error('No position object given!');
      }
      this.lat = parseFloat(position.lat);
      this.lon = parseFloat(position.lon);

      this.timestamp = position.timestamp;
      this.heading = position.heading;
      this.speed = position.speed;
    };

    Position.prototype.getLatLng = function () {
      return new L.LatLng(this.lat, this.lon);
    };


    function Positions(positions) {
      if (!(positions instanceof Array)) {
        throw new Error('No positions array given!');
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        this.positions.push(new Position(positions[i]));
      }
    };
```

Comment: because there is no `this.positions` defined

Comment: Maybe you want `positions` (not `this.positions`)?

Comment: The only time you call `push` in that code is inside `Positions`, which is a function you never call in that code. So whatever the problem is, it isn't revealed by your question. It probably boils down to "How does `this` work in JavaScript?" though.

Comment: In response to comments/answers about replacing this.positions with just positions... I doubt the goal was to append items from an array to itself in an (infinite) loop, but rather to copy to a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        positions.push(new Position(positions[i]));
      }
```

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop. `positions.length` will continue to grow as you push new items onto it.

Comment: Its turn out "this.positions" should have been "return positions". You give the correct answer first.

Comment: @JermaineHercules, how is this a correct answer? It will crash your page.

Answer (score 2):

**this.positions** isn't defined in this function. Try to define it before push operation.

```
this.position = [];
```